# Give boost score within Django query set that matches a given list of ids

Tags: django, django-queryset, recommendation-engine

Given a set of ids,

```
class Article(model.Model):
    hotness = FloatField()
    content = TextField()
    created = DateField()

    @property
    def calculate_hotness(self):
        return (self.created.replace(tzinfo=None)-datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds() 

# The hotness field is updated by a cronjob hourly.

recommended_ids = [1,2,3,4]

Article.objects.order_by('-hotness').???
```

I would like like to give articles with ids in `recommended_ids` a boost of score of 1.5x.

Comment: Can you please minimize your description and explain what exactly you need, seems you need something simple. And also share your models too.

Comment: I think you're really confusing a search engine with django's models.

Comment: @Jason I don't think so. I use elasticsearch for search when I need to search based on text.

Comment: but no boosting exists natively in a non-search engine db.  you might be interested in ths: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzcvewgqYog